# Cannot step through code in debugger (Android)

Tags: android, debugging

For some reason I can't step through the code in the debugger. I am not trying to step through Android source code, just code that resides in my project. My build paths are setup to include it, but whenever I try stepping over anything it gives me a "Source not found" message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont think the poster wants to step through the java source code.  What he wants to do is avoid stepping into the core libraries.  Fortunately eclipse does let you do this using step filters (though why this isnt enabled by default ill never know, i would have thought people wanting to debug the core libraries would be the edge case ...).  To do this, you can go to **Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Debug -> Step Filtering**, turn it on and check the packages you want to automatically step over (i check them all).

See this post for more information along with some great screenshots - http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t83338.rhtml

Comment: you're welcome - and thanks to you i now have some points so i can start doing stuff here on SO!  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Android SDK doesn't include source code. 
How do you setup your build path?
Check these articles, if you want to browse android framework source code under eclipse and set break point. But I did not try these methodology recently.

Browsing Android Source in Eclipse

http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/11/01/browsing-android-source-in-eclipse

View Android Source Code in Eclipse

http://blog.michael-forster.de/2008/12/view-android-source-code-in-eclipse.html

Comment: I am not trying to browse through Android source code. I am  trying to browse through MY source code.