# Extras with Intent class are not passed android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have some data put in Intent object however they are not passed into the new started activity. I try to debug the application and when the debugger come to the line where the extras from Intent object are passed to new variable i got these error[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's not an error, it just means you don't have the android source code on your PC. Just step over any android system calls and you should be able to continue, or click "Step Return" once you get this screen and you should return to your own code.

There's also a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3964993/1236185) which explains how to turn on "Step Filters", so that eclipse automatically will skip stepping into any android source.

Also see:
http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t83338.rhtml